# How to use nokogiri to choose a table only if the text in the preceding p-elements contains a specific term?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a bunch of financial reports from which I need to extract a few specific tables. I have been using Ruby (and I'm fairly new to programming) to accomplish this and so far I've had good results using a keyword-matching system (matching terms in the tables). However I would like to use a second approach where the text of the p-elements above a table are screened for keywords and if a match is found the table should be put to a file. I've been searching all day (mostly playing with xpath (and this link REALLY helped: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)) and unfortunately I haven't gotten very far. An example of the sheets I need to process is found here:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1583671/000106299315005260/form10k.htm#page_15

Take these p-elements with the associated Balance sheet table for example:

```html
<p align="center"><b>SCIENCE TO CONSUMERS, INC. </b></p>
<p align="center"><b>BALANCE SHEET </b><br>
</p>
<table style="BORDER-COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; " width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <tbody><tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" width="12%" nowrap=""><b>May 31,</b> </td>
    <td align="center" width="2%" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" width="1%" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" width="12%" nowrap=""><b>May 31, 2014</b> </td>
  <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="center"><b>ASSETS</b> </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="center" width="12%" nowrap=""><b>2015</b> </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="center" width="2%" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="center" width="1%" nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="center" width="12%" nowrap="">&nbsp; </td>
  <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Current Assets </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Cash and cash equivalents </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">1,749 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">&nbsp;5,171 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#E6EFFF">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Total Current Assets </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">1,749    </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">5,171    </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#e6efff">Total Assets </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;1,749 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;5,171 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#e6efff"><b>LIABILITIES AND STOCKHOLDERS’
      EQUITY</b> </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Liabilities </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#e6efff">Current Liabilities </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Loan from director </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">8,891</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">8,217    </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Total Liabilities </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">8,891    </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">8,217    </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Stockholders’ Equity </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="12%">&nbsp; </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Common stock,
      par value $0.001; 525,000,000 shares
      authorized,&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;29,900,000 shares
      issued and outstanding; </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">29,900 </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">29,750 </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Additional paid in capital </td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right" width="12%">61,100</td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right" width="12%">16,250 </td>
    <td align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Deficit accumulated
      during the development stage </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">(98,142</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">) </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">(49,046</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">) </td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Total Stockholders’ Equity </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">(7,142</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">) </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="right" width="12%">(3,046</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 1px solid" align="left" width="2%">) </td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp; </td>
    <td width="2%" bgcolor="#e6efff">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">Total Liabilities and Stockholders’ Equity </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="1%">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="right" width="12%">&nbsp;1,749 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="1%">$</td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="right" width="12%">&nbsp;5,171 </td>
    <td style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000000 3px double" align="left" width="2%">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

So it should for example detect the "BALANCE SHEET" text and then write the table to a file.

This is what I have found so far:

```
output = File.open("output.htm", 'w')
htm = File.open( "a.htm", "r+" )
htm = Nokogiri::HTML(open(htm)) do |config|
   config.noblanks
end    
allelements = htm.xpath('//table | //p')
allelements.each_with_index do |element, index|
   if element.xpath('//table//*[contains(text(),\'Balance\')]') 
      output.puts element
   #if element.xpath('//p//*[contains(text(),\'Balance\')]') 
   #check next five elements and if one equals "table" then 
   #write that table to the output file.
   end
end
```

Obviously this code is incomplete but even this doesn't work as the output file contains all the p- and table-elements which I don't understand (I would expect only the table elements to be put in the output file at this point).

So thank you for reading this post and any ideas/remarks are welcome!

Comment: So you need table after `p` with certain text? In this case after `p` with _BALANCE SHEET_?

Comment: That is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after finding the nokogiri ".name" method which makes it a peace of cake. This code works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

output = File.open("output.htm", 'w')
financial_file = File.open( "a.htm", "r+" )

original_financial_file_downcased = File.read(financial_file).downcase
downcased_financial_file = File.open("downcased_financial_file.htm", "w+" )
original_financial_file_downcased.each_line do |line|
downcased_financial_file.puts line
end      
downcased_financial_file.flush 

nokogiri_cleaned_financial_report = Nokogiri::HTML(open(downcased_financial_file)) do |config|
config.noblanks
end


allelements = nokogiri_cleaned_financial_report.xpath('//table | //p')
allelements.each_with_index do |element, index|
if element.name == "table"
   number_of_p_elements_to_assess = 5    
   number_of_p_elements_to_assess.times do 
      if /balance sheets/i.match(allelements[index-number_of_p_elements_to_assess].text)
         output.puts element
      end
   number_of_p_elements_to_assess -= 1
   end      
end
```

Thanks to everyone who bothered to read the post.

Regards,

Usui